# Issues copying a bucketfile to local disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've ran through the entire sequence that I believe I needed to do, but I am still getting an `invalid argument type error` while trying to copy my file locally. What am I doing wrong here?

```
vagrant@dev:~$ aws s3 ls s://bucketname-vagrant

A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist

vagrant@dev:~$ aws s3 ls bucketname-vagrant
2015-03-30 14:06:02  285061467 or_vagrant.sql.tar.gz
2015-03-30 13:55:01  102642228 or_vagrant.sql.xz

vagrant@dev:~$ aws s3 ls bucketname-vagrant/or_vagrant.sql.xz
2015-03-30 13:55:01  102642228 or_vagrant.sql.xz
vagrant@dev:~$ aws s3 cp bucketname-vagrant/or_vagrant.sql.xz /tmp/

usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Path> or <S3Path> <LocalPath> or <S3Path> <S3Path>
Error: Invalid argument type
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`s3` is not deprecated. [`s3` and `s3api` are on different tiers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-s3.html). `s3api` is the API-level, while `s3` has the high-level commands.

## ls

The problem is that you have a typo in `s3://` in your first command.

```
$ aws s3 ls s://bucketname-vagrant
A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

I can replicate that error with my own bucket. This works:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucketname-vagrant
```

#cp

```
$ aws s3 cp bucketname-vagrant/or_vagrant.sql.xz /tmp/
```

The problem here is that aws-cli doesn't know if you have a local directory named `bucketname-vagrant` or not. You can fix that by using the `s3://` syntax:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://bucketname-vagrant/or_vagrant.sql.xz /tmp/
```

Again, I replicated that locally.

```
$ aws s3 cp bucket/test.txt /tmp/
usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Path> or <S3Path> <LocalPath> or <S3Path> <S3Path>
Error: Invalid argument type

$ aws s3 cp s3://bucket/test.txt /tmp/
download: s3://bucket/test.txt to /tmp/keybase.txt
```

Comment: The solution given under **ls** has the exact same typo as the question. It should read `$ aws s3 ls s3://bucketname-vagrant`.

Answer (score -2):

Seems to be that S3 is deprecated in favor of s3api, this worked

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket bucketname-vagrant --key or_vagrant.sql.tar.gz or_vagrant.sql.tar.gz
```